# How to suppress page ejects when using \chapterstyle{article} in the Memoir class for LaTeX?

Tags: latex, article, lyx, memoir

I just started using the article chapterstyle in Memoir.
I'm composing in LyX, with each section of the article in a child document.
When compiling from the main document, I want each section to be numbered as follows:

```
1. Introduction
2. Related Literature
2.1 Literature from Long Ago
2.2 Literature from Yesterday
... Etc.
n-1. Conclusion
n. References
```

To accomplish this the top-level section headings use \chapter. Numbering, formatting, etc. is perfect. Except: each \chapter is triggering a page eject, and I can't figure out how to fix this.

What's the easiest way to make each \chapter (section of the article) begin below the preceding one when there's space on the page?

Answer (score 0):

`memoir` has a macro called `\clearforchapter` that normally ensures that chapters start at the correct page. You can disable it like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand{\clearforchapter}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

test

\chapter{test2}

test
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this should work, but it isn't. Perhaps the reason is I'm using LyX, and each section is a child document. I only redefined \clearforchapter in the main (parent) document. Do you suppose I have to do this in every child?

Comment: @Gnosos Can you make a [mre] and export it as tex code?